# Key bindings for interrupt execution in Python Sublime REPL

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I'm using REPL extension for Sublime text 3 for my python projects. Currently when I want to interrupt a running script I have to close to close the REPL window to stop execution and all computations are so far are lost. 
I was wondering if anybody knows how to interrupt an execution and have a short cut or key bindings for that

Answer (score 1):

On OS X and Linux, the key binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> executes the `subprocess_repl_send_signal` command with signal 2 (SIGINT), the equivalent of `KeyboardInterrupt` in Python.

For some reason, though, SublimeREPL's Windows keymap doesn't include this command, and instead the keybinding executes the `repl_clear` command, which just clears all the text in the view. To get around this, select **`Preferences → Key Bindings—User`** and add the following:

```js
{ 
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"], 
    "command": "subprocess_repl_send_signal", 
    "args": {"signal": 2},
    "context":
    [
        { 
            "key": "setting.repl", 
            "operator": "equal", 
            "operand": true 
        }
    ]
}
```

If this is your first custom key binding, make sure the command above is surrounded by square brackets `[]`.

Comment: When I try to add it, sublime show me an error message saying "[WinError 6] The handle is invalid". Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above (a long time ago) the key bindings aren't present for Windows. However, one can **Mouse Right Click** to open a context menu. From here there are menu options for Kill and Restart. You can also open a sub-menu which allows you send those and other signals including `SIGINT`.